# Can't understand why this styled component doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

```js
const CopyButton = styled(() => <i className="fa fa-copy"/>)`
  &:before {
    color: red;
  }
`
```

What am I doing wrong that this component doesn't work? It even doesn't apply `className` on component.
[image]

Comment: You have to assign the styled className to the `i` element: ```styled(({className}) => <i className={`${className} fa fa-copy`} />```.

Comment: Bingo!!! Knew it but totally forget about it. Can you make an answer so I will approve it?